# How to write "probability that result of objective function is lower than y" in LinearConstraint using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have the following working optimization problem:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint
random.seed(123)


# assumptions
d = np.array([1.3,  10])
p = np.array([random.randint(700, 950) / 1000 for _ in range(100)])


scenarios = np.array([[1],
                      [0]])
r = scenarios * d - 1           # returns per scenario


def obj(f):
    return -1 * np.sum(p * np.log(np.sum(1 + r * f, axis=1))[:, None])


f0 = [0, 0]
constr_1 = LinearConstraint(np.ones((1, 2)), lb=0, ub=1)
constr_2 = LinearConstraint(np.eye(2), lb=0, ub=1)
constraints = [constr_1, constr_2]
res = minimize(fun=obj, x0=f0, method='trust-constr', constraints=constraints)
print(res.x)
```

This is an attempt to implement the [Kelly-ECC method](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02814.pdf):

[image: ECC method]

I would like to introduce a `LinearConstraint` that makes sure that for `x`% of the estimates in `p` the result of the objective function is lower than `y`.
So, the constraint would look like

> P[y >= obj] >= (1 - x)

How do I create such a `LinearConstraint`?

Comment: 1) Can you clarify what `y` is? 2) This doesn't seem like a linear constraint, because a linear constraint must be a linear functinon of the X values, and this has a log. You may need a [NonLinearConstaint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html).

Comment: In "real life", what is the actual distribution of _p_? Is it actually uniform?

Comment: No, it can also be bimodal sometimes

Comment: Your second linear constraint is really just variable bounds. Is there any particular reason you've expressed this as a constraint instead of bounds?

Comment: Not per se, I saw some messages on the github and here that there could be problems using bounds with `trust-constraint`-algorithm

Comment: I read through this again and now I'm less sure that it makes sense. You say _percent of the estimates in p_, but the objective is only ever a function of the _sum_ of _p_. I found this when reducing the objective to its simplest equivalent form. So what specifically does it mean for _p_ to be involved in a distribution for y? Do you take as fixed the population size of _p_, transform the distribution of _p_ to a distribution for the sum of _n_ random variables, apply your objective function to this new sum distribution? That seems unlikely.

Comment: When `alpha=0.5` I want to make sure that for at least 50 of the estimates in `p` the result of `obj` is smaller than `y`. Where `y` could be for example -1. Idea is based on the "ECC"-method of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02814.pdf)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256771/discussion-between-reinderien-and-hja24).

Answer (score 2):

Replace your objective definition with the equivalent

```py
    inner = np.log((1 + r*f).sum(axis=1))
    cost = -inner.sum() * p.sum()
```

During program start-up, do some pre-processing. Calculate the empirical CDF like

```py
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)
d = np.array((1.3, 10))
p = rand.uniform(low=0.700, high=0.950, size=100)

# for gamma% of the estimates in p the result of the objective function is lower than y
# P[obj <= y] >= gamma
p_sorted = np.sort(p)
p_cdf = np.arange(p.size)/(p.size - 1)
```

Then choose a `y`, and also pre-compute its probability from the CDF:

```py
# Probability that the random variable is <= y
y = 0.85
py = p_cdf[p_sorted.searchsorted(y)]
```

During the confidence-interval constraint (which must be declared as a `NonlinearConstraint`) function, calculate the cost by calling the objective function, find its position in the CDF:

```
# Probability that the random variable is less than the current cost
idx = min(p_cdf.size - 1, p_sorted.searchsorted(cost))
pcost = p_cdf[idx]
```

then with this probability and `py`, you can derive the relative probability which will be compared to the lower bound you set on the constraint object. This will behave better if you perform smoothing or fitting on the CDF.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I like the CDF-angle. How would the `NonlinearConstraint` be actually defined? Can you share your full code?

Comment: I have full code but I'm not confident that it's correct, especially because your description of the confidence constraint and your formula do not match. Why is a log being taken on `y`?

Comment: The log is not necessary, I will edit the question